# How do I access the Flask API running on my local system, on another system?

Tags: python, flask, python-2.x

I am running the flask API using the following statement:

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', threaded=True, use_reloader=False)
```

My system IP is: 10.0.0.1, and I am on WIFI right now.

The API is accessible to local system via following URL:

```
127.0.0.1:5000/api/version/search/?text='search'
```

or via following:

```
10.0.0.1:5000/api/version/search/?text='search'
```

Now I have another system connected with the same network through WIFI and am trying to access the API through the URL:

```
10.0.0.1:5000/api/version/search/?text='search'
```

But it is saying : `10.0.0.1 refused to connect`
Hence , I tried this:

```
0.0.0.0:5000/api/version/search/?text='search'
```

But still I got the same error:  `0.0.0.0 refused to connect`

Kindly, let me know how I can access the API through same wifi connect on another system?

Comment: I guess you would need port forwarding here. Not sure though.

Comment: Port forwarding? Why so? If I am in the same network then why would it be needed. Can you tell me what I need to do for port forwarding?

Comment: Is there some firewall in between? Can you ping the other machine? Is that on a vpn?

Comment: @syntonym I guess there might be firewall. I am trying to ping the machine but it is not moving forward.. still waiting. There is no VPN.

Comment: If you can't ping than either ICMP is filtered or you can not reach the other machine at all. The the network "under your control"? Or do you have some network admins that might be cooperative?

Comment: @syntonym yes the network is in my hands right now. for some reasons I have to have access to the network. Else there is a network admin aligned with me.

Comment: I would guess that on WIFI client-client communication is filtered for security reasons. Can you move one machine from WIFI to lan? Often these restrictions are only for wifi. Generally some network person should be able to help you better, I guess the problem is not the application but the network layer. For adhoc stuff you could also do some ssh hopping client -> server -> client if only client-client is filtered.

Comment: Ok I will try to move on LAN... But it would be great if I get a solution for WIFI. It is widely used by me and I cannot remain connected to cable for long time.

Answer (score 0):

in host argument (in run function) set your ip in your local network by example:

```
app.run(host='192.168.1.100', threaded=True, use_reloader=False)
```

you can get your ip using `ifconfig` command in linux (or `ip addr` command) or using `ipconfig` in windows.

Comment: But I guess with the IP set as `0.0.0.0` it should be available everywhere... What do you say?

Comment: Sorry.. I tried your answer.. It is not working at all.

Comment: Even, I guess syntonym  is right.. the ICMP filter issue might be there as I am unable to ping the IP.

Comment: ICMP is only ping and other diagnosis stuff, but it seems that all traffic is forbidden between these both machines.

Comment: it should work ... check your firewall .. which os do you use ?

Comment: @JafferWilson You must tell me which os do you use
anyway if you use linux distro you must make rule in iptables like that
`iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 5000 -j ACCEPT`

Comment: My current OS is Windows 10 and the PC I am trying to access the API is through Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Then you should allow connection in windows firewall, read this article https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345310(v=sql.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be the firewall issue to me. `Port 5000` needs to be set among the allowed ports in the firewall. Since you're running Ubuntu on your host machine, try the following command:

`sudo ufw allow 5000`

If that doesn't work, you need to set the iptables rules